# How to store values from a service to an array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, service, response

I have a service with getter and setter methods, they return me `id: number` and `title: String` from my dialog component.
I need to store the values from the response to my `data` array, but I just cant figure out how.
For example:

```
    0: {id: 0, title: "UK ",…}
    1: {id: 1, title: "Usd ",…}
    2: {id: 2, title: "ff ",…}
    3: {id: 3, title: "yy ",…}
    4: {id: 4, title: "nn ",…}
    5: {id: 5, title: "mh ",…}
    6: {id: 6, title: "tr ",…}
    7: {id: 7, title: "es ",…}
```

I would be so grateful if you guys can help me out.

Here is what I got so far:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  clickEventsubscription: Subscription

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  id: number;
  title: String;
  data: any = [];

  constructor(private share: ShareDataService) {
    this.clickEventsubscription = this.share.getClickEvent().subscribe(() => {
      this.initialize();
    })
  }

  initialize() {
    this.id = this.share.getId();
    this.title = this.share.getTitle();
    console.log(this.id, this.title);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-dialog></app-dialog>
<h2>Add values of my service into array:</h2>
<button (click)="initialize()"></button>
```

**share-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareDataService {

  title: String;
  id: number;

  getId() {
    return this.id
  }

  getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendClickEvent() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getClickEvent(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you also share code inside the `getClickEvent()`? Inside subscribe method, there will be 3 methods next(), error() and complete(). Where next() method will holds your data if getClickEvent returns something

Comment: I edited now, thanks for your help. You can find the data service inside my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, there are several solutions to solve this
but the simplest way is to create an new object every time you trigger the initialize method which goes as follows

change this

```
initialize() {

    this.id = this.share.getId();
    this.title = this.share.getTitle();
    console.log(this.id, this.title);

 }
```

to the following

```
initialize(): void {

    this.id = this.share.getId();
    this.title = this.share.getTitle();

    const newData = {
      id: this.id,
      title: this.title
    };

    this.data.push(newData);
 }
```

There are some syntax errors and ordering issue in your code both the service and app component which should be solved (depends on what version of angular you are using).

Also you have to declare instant fields before instance declaration of instance method, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface

move this to the top of your class in share-data.service.ts

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and your time, you helped me a lot. I am trying hard to learn Angular by myself and I have to say that it isn't really easy for me, even if you don't have a teacher. But people like you make me feel not to be alone and motivating me to keep learning and I can't thank you enough for your support. I hope that you will continue to help people in the future and hopefully I will be able to do so in the future too. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, I am so happy that my answer was helpful to you, as a self learner I have to say just keep on experimenting on different situations and try to solve the problems and learn, after few months this framework would be as easy as a cake.